# Uniqueness of radially symmetric eigenfunctions

Tags: analysis, eigenfunctions, elliptic-equations

Given a smooth radially symmetric potential $V = V(|x|)$ in the unit ball $B_1\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, consider the eigenvalue problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\Delta \varphi + V \varphi = \lambda \varphi & \text{ in } B_1\\
\varphi = 0 & \text{ on } \partial B_1,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume that *all* eigenfunctions as above are **radially symmetric** for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can we prove that these solutions are also unique?

Answer (score 1):

The eigenfunctions won’t be radially symmetric in general. Using separation of variables, you can write $\phi=f(r)g(\omega)$ with $\omega$ the coordinates over the unit sphere. $g$ is therefore a spherical harmonic:
$$
\Delta_{S^{n-1}}g=-l(l+n-2)g
$$
with $l\in\mathbb N$. Your radial problem is now:
$$
f’’+\frac{n-1}{r}f’-\frac{l(l+n-2)}{r^2}f+Vf=\lambda f
$$
and using the using change of variable $h=r^{(n-1)/2}f$, you reduce the problem to a 1D Schrödinger equation:
$$
h’’-\frac{\left(l+\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \left(l+\frac{n-3}{2}\right)}{r^2}h+Vh=\lambda h
$$
with the norm given by the usual 1D $L^2$ norm:
$$
||h||^2=\int_0^\infty|h|^2dr
$$
You can interpret the additional potential $-\frac{\left(l+\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \left(l+\frac{n-3}{2}\right)}{r^2}$ as the centrifugal potential.

The usual results for 1D system therefore apply like the usual Wronskian argument. Generally, it comes from the Sturm-Liouville theory on the half line, which guarantees the nondegeneracy of the eigenvectors characterized by their number of nodes.

Hope this helps.